# Connecting Log4j to ipython notebook stderr in a java/python project using py4j

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, log4j, jupyter-notebook

I have a project that uses java, scala and Apache Spark to do distributed computations on genomic data.  Using py4j and mimicking the PySpark model, we expose a python API that calls into the JVM.  Our goal has been to bring this model into jupyter notebooks, which has been pretty easy so far, with one lingering problem: logging.

#### The problem

We (and Spark) use log4j to write log messages to a log file and stderr.  This stderr is the stderr for the java process, so if I run two commands from the jupyter notebook:

```
print('foo')
info('bar')  # calls log4j logger.info in JVM
```

I see 'foo' written to the jupyter cell, but 'bar' is written to the terminal running the jupyter process.

#### My goal

Connect log4j to the jupyter notebook so that log4j messages are written to jupyter cells, instead of the terminal.

#### What I've tried

The java log4j.ConsoleAppender is writing to the java stderr.  So, we're going to need to route the java stderr through jupyter somehow, right?  This may involve using `System.setOut(...)` with a `PrintStream` object hooked up to the jupyter process, but I'm not yet sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by using a separate socket to communicate between Java and Python. Here's the commit diff: https://github.com/hail-is/hail/commit/93d7e95a82ab39501eede7ecb301538bcd013ea8