# How to show the spark progress bar in Jupyter notebook (using pyspark)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I want to see the progress bar in the Jupyter notebook. The progress bar is only shown in the terminal and does not pass over to the notebook.

But this is not the case when you use Scala in the jupyter notebook (you can see the progress bar)

There is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885220/connecting-log4j-to-ipython-notebook-stderr-in-a-java-python-project-using-py4j) asking the same thing.

My jupyter version is 4.3.0

By the way, the progress bar is on since I can see it in the terminal.

Comment: have you seen https://krishnan-r.github.io/sparkmonitor/?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of Jupyter extensions that allow you to do this.

- Have a look at `mozilla/jupyter-spark`

  - https://github.com/mozilla/jupyter-spark
- and at `krishnan-r/sparkmonitor`

  - https://github.com/krishnan-r/sparkmonitor

Both links above have installation instructions and examples how they work.

Comment: is there a way to install it using jupyter terminal?